# How do I add a class on click to a parent element in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="cell">
  <div class="offset-container pull-left">
    <i data-ng-click="doCtrlStuff()"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you click the `<i>`, I want to add an `active` class to the parent that has `.cell` currently. How is this doable with AngularJS?

Comment: Just a quick word of advice: next time don't ask 1 question and then ask yet another in some comments, especially when you seem to already know you had 2 questions. Put them all in the original post so that people can help you easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, according to your last comment, if your cells are in a loop you should have mentioned that in your question. I'm gonna assume you use ng-repeat.

I have something like this which works. The `active` class also get removed if you click another.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="cell in [0,1,2]" data-ng-class="{cell:true, active:index=='{{$index}}'}">
    <div class="offset-container pull-left">
        <i data-ng-click="activate($index)">Activate Me</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.activate= function(index){
      $scope.index=index;
  };
```

Comment: @NicolasMose is there a way to remove active class if clicked the same button again (toggle class - add and remove)?

Comment: @NicolasMose I did the changes to your code as I requested to you above. I got it answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620253/how-to-add-active-class-to-this-parent-on-child-button-is-clicked-and-toggle

Comment: This works correctly, just that instead of `activate('{{$index}}')` it would be `activate($index)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, using `ng-class`

```
<div class="cell" ng-class="{'active': isActive==true}">
  <div class="offset-container pull-left">
    <i data-ng-click="doCtrlStuff()">clicky</i>     
  </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.doCtrlStuff = function(){
        $scope.isActive = true;
    }             
}
```

Comment: How can I set all of the other `cell`'s to not be active when one is clicked?

Comment: Depends on how your code is setup. Can you add to your sample code so that we can see exactly what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="cell" ng-class="{'active': isActive}">
  <div class="offset-container pull-left">
    <i data-ng-click="isActive = !isActive"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass

```
<div data-ng-class="{cell:true, active:clickedIcon}">
  <div class="offset-container pull-left">
    <i data-ng-click="doCtrlStuff()"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

You would use a class:boolean pattern for the ng-class expression.

And in your controller:

```
$scope.doCtrlStuff = function() {
    $scope.clickedIcon = true;
}
```

UPDATE:

If you want to do a radio button:

```
<div data-ng-class="{cell:true, active:clickedDogIcon}">
  <div class="offset-container pull-left">
    <i data-ng-click="doDogStuff()"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-ng-class="{cell:true, active:clickedCatIcon}">
  <div class="offset-container pull-left">
    <i data-ng-click="doCatStuff()"></i>
  </div>
</div>

$scope.doDogStuff = function() {
    $scope.clickedDogIcon = true;
    $scope.clickedCatIcon = false;
}
$scope.doCatStuff = function() {
    $scope.clickedDogIcon = false;
    $scope.clickedCatIcon = true;
}
```

Comment: How can I remove the `active` class from all other `cell`s?

Comment: I would have a different variable for each parent. So you can do clickedIcon1, clickedIcon2, etc... and set the others to false so that ng-class will remove that class when they are false.

Comment: The `cell`s are in a loop. So I can't do the 1, 2, 3, etc approach

Comment: If it's in a loop, then you might just want to do jqlite (which is part of Angular) or jquery selectors using addClass & removeClass.

Comment: Yes this last part is really bad practice and could get very messy very quickly. What if you have 10 different cells. Yo would need 10 different functions each changing 10 variables.